# How to import sequelize library in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sequelize.js

I am using https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize with sqlite in react-native project. But after install it, I import

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
```

and run project I get this error. Please Help! thank you.

[image]

Comment: After 3 years, do you still have the same error or you have it working now?

Answer (score 0):

I setup a quick demo app using `react-native init` to try for myself. I'm getting the same error.

In your browser, open up your bundle URL And you'll see the error more clearly.  http://packager.e3-nmz.tuanbaros.demo-sqlite.exp.direct/node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/home/nguyen.thanh.tuan/Downloads/learning/react-native/demo-sqlite/mode_module/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles

This is the key part of the error...

```
TransformError: [...]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js: require() must have a single string literal argument
```

I'm not sure what this means, but the packager is having trouble parsing the sequelize package itself. I would recommend you open an issue with the sequelize repo.

Just for reference, here's the code I wrote to test this...

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  state = {
    connection: 'not yet connected'
  }

 componentDidMount() {
   const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
     host: 'localhost',
     dialect: 'sqlite',
     pool: {
       max: 5,
       min: 0,
       acquire: 30000,
       idle: 10000
     },

     storage: ':memory:'
   });

   sequalize
    .authenticate()
    .then( () => {
      this.setState({ connection: 'Success: SQLite Connection'});
    })
    .catch( err => {
      this.setState({ connection: 'Error: ${err}'})
    });
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Let's try to sequelize, shall we?
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {this.state.connection}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From React Native 0.49+ the require directive will only take a string literal.  Sequelize builds the argument to require dynamically which is why you are getting the error that you saw.  Many libraries have this problem as documented by this issue:  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16216

You could try reverting to 0.48.4 since it does not have this restriction.